# Move side widget "Help improve the site" to the bottom of the review queues on smaller screens

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, responsive-design

When viewing the /review page on smaller screens, the "Help improve the site" widget, normally shown as a side widget on the right, is now shown *above* the review queues themselves. Can it please be moved to the *bottom* instead? Right now I have to scroll half a page to see all review queues (users with other phones even more), while in the previous version I could immediately see the size of all queues.

It get that it might be important for newer reviewers, but most veterans already know what's stated in that box. They are also probably more likely to review on smartphones than newer users (I didn't even know it was possible until a year ago).

Alternative solutions like hiding or collapsing the widget (like the [review instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXKH5.png)) are fine with me, as long as the system or the browser remembers that setting and I only have to dismiss this widget/banner at most once per site.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes please. On my phone I don't even see half of the Close Votes lines ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz0PV.png)). (and it's not a particularly small model)

Comment: I disagree with this because this banner might be an important introduction to new users. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/07/membership-has-its-privileges/. As a possible solution this banner could be made collapsible.

Comment: @MEE or make it disappear once you've reviewed a certain number of posts; like when you're under 2k you have that big fat yellow banner about how edits should be done, contain etc etc, and then it disappears once you've reach the "instant edit" privilege. About it collapsing - sure, if it can be disabled from account settings, and not each and every time one accesses the page.

Comment: @Jenayah no I mean like the GDPR or mini-tour banners that are hidden forever on one side when you close them.

Comment: @MEE ah, okay, that works too. Although these links can be helpful to users who just got the privilege and aren't sure how to review - especially when you unlock the queues one after another (First Post/Late Answer, then Close/Reopen, then Tag Wiki Edits... all of them having their not-so-obvious guidelines)

Comment: +1 for hiding the widget. Hiding could be restricted to all users with one or more review silver or gold badge. This way it will still be useful for users doing their first reviews.

Comment: Even more extreme example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iDzq.png. I see no (zero, 0%) of the review queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Kristina & Aaron put some work into reducing the *verbosity* of the text in that widget. This allows it to be shown consistently *without* pushing the review queues off-screen, even on very, very small screens:

[image: Chrome's mobile device simulator showing the dashboard adjusting to different device formats]

This is some damn fine *responsive design*: no information is lost or hidden, but adjusts smoothly to fit into the space provided. Donno if you can see it, but *even the text gets smaller* as the available space drops. That's awful fancy!

That information is not unimportant. You may've seen it hundreds or thousands of times, but every day new people are seeing it for the very first time, and learning what this is all about in the process. With a flick of your finger, you can scroll past it; they will hopefully take a moment to read it - now that it isn't off-screen somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it's a fancy design, no complaints there. Hats off! (Oh, wait, we already did that a week ago.) One of the golden rules of UX design is that important content goes on the left and top, less important content on the right and bottom. What's so important about ~820px that the priority changes there?

Comment: What about making it closeable (maybe after some reviews)? You don’t seem to have responded to this. Shall I write a new feature-request?

Comment: I recommend giving yourself a bit of time to acclimate, @MEE. It looks *different* than it did a couple of days ago, and YMMV... But I actually see *more of the queues* on the first page of the new layout than I did in the old one, *even with the explanation*. It's a remarkably efficient layout, and I'd rather not add complexity unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Shog9 I understand this and I don’t have a problem with cheese being moved (I recently got a cheese board for this ;)) but please look at the image in my latest comment on this question. I see nothing on Quantum Computing. This is probably also related to the sponsor icon. Maybe making it smaller or place it differently if you don’t want to touch the review info box.

Comment: Mmm, yeah, that's not ideal - I'd report that as a bug, @MEE; donno what phone that is, but maybe we can just hide it entirely at *very* small screen sizes.

Comment: @Shog9 I am not sure what to hide: the sponsorship-label or the info box? The info-box might be a solution but I am not sure whether your contract allows you to hide the sponsorship-label on all sites in some situation...

Comment: Don't worry about it; I'm just guessing as to a solution. Report what you're seeing, and provide details on your phone and browser @MEE - first step is reproducing the problem; at the resolution of your image, I get a *very* different layout... So you're working on a high-res screen at a very low "logical resolution", and that's throwing a wrench into things.

Comment: @Shog9 I believe it is the latest mobile chrome for iOS 12.1.2. The phone seems to be an iPhone 5s. There should be no strange settings.

Comment: Ok, @MEE - turns out Aaron is also using a similarly tiny iPhone, so he was able to reproduce the issue. After much discussion, we're gonna address this by drastically reducing the verbosity of the text itself - thus making the entire help blurb less bulky.